# iOS code redemption sheet does not display app name properly

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

When using the [presentCodeRedemptionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3566726-presentcoderedemptionsheet) API, on TestFlight build the screen does not render the app name and offer price correctly (see screenshot).

Will it work in the production app or is there some setting in ASC or app bundle I need to fill out? The app name displays correctly everywhere else, in the store and in the system.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?